# How can I find the nonzero values in a MATLAB cells array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

The following code generates an cell array Index [1x29], where each cell is an array [29x6]:

```
for i = 1 : size(P1_cell,1)
    
    for j = 1 : size(P1_cell,2)

        [Lia,Lib] = ismember(P1_cell{i,j},PATTERNS_FOR_ERANOS_cell{1},'rows'); 
        Index1(i,j) = Lib  % 29x6

    end

    Index{i} = Index1; % 1x29
end
```

How can I find the nonzero values in Index array?, i.e. generate an array with the number of non-zero values in each row of the Index1 array. I tried the following loop, but it doesn't work, it creates conflict with the previous one:

```
for i = 1 : length(Index)
                    
    for j = 1 : length(Index)
    
        Non_ceros = length(find(Index{:,i}(j,:))); %%  I just need the length of the find function output
            
    end
end
```

I need help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nnz()` (number of non-zeros) function can be used to evaluate the number of non-zero elements. To obtain the specific positive values you can index the array by using the indices returned by the `find()` function. I used some random test data but it should work for 29 by 6 sized arrays as well.

```
%Random test data%
Index{1} = [5 2 3 0 zeros(1,25)];
Index{2} = [9 2 3 1 zeros(1,25)];
Index{3} = [5 5 5 5 zeros(1,25)];


%Initializing and array to count the number of zeroes%
Non_Zero_Counts = zeros(length(Index),1);
 

for Row_Index = 1: length(Index)
    %Evaluating the number of positive values%
    Array = Index{Row_Index};
    Non_Zero_Counts(Row_Index) = nnz(Array);

    %Retrieving the positive values%  
    Positive_Indices = find(Array);
    PositiveElements{Row_Index} = Array(Positive_Indices);
   
    disp(Non_Zero_Counts(Row_Index) + " Non-Zero Elements ");
    disp(PositiveElements{Row_Index});
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer.
My problem is not finding all the values in the array, but by rows independently and storing those values in an array. The array of cells Index (1x29) contains the arrays Index1 (29x6) where I want, by rows (29) to find the number of values that are not zeros. It is that nnz returns all the values that are not zero in the whole array. Thanks for your time.

Comment: To clarify you want to find the number of non-zero elements in each row of sub-arrays? Where, the sub-arrays are the 29 by 6 arrays stored in each cell of the 1 by 29 cell array.

Comment: If that is the case, we might need a more detailed explanation of what how you want your output data/result array formatted.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I want it can be solved with the code I appended using nnz(). What happened is that I had an error in another part of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 for i = 1 : length(Index)
     for j = 1 : length(Index)        
         Non_ceros(i,j) = nnz(Index{:,i}(j,:));
     end       
 end
```